# Pygame Calculate Angle of Reflection of Collision betweeen masks

Tags: python, vector, pygame

I encountered an issue in my brick breaker game where the paddle has round edges and i want to reflect the ball with perfect angle, i was using angle and sin and cos for the direction, but i moved to vectors after a recommendation, i made a similar problem for the sake of simplicity.
here is the code:

```
import sys

import pygame

pygame.init()

w, h = 1200, 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
clock = pygame.Clock()

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((10, 10))
        self.image.set_colorkey((0,0,0))
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, (255, 0, 0), (5, 5), 3)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (x, y) )
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
        self.velocity = pygame.Vector2(0, -10)

    def update(self, circlex, circley, circle_mask):
        if self.rect.y < 0 or self.rect.y > 800:
            self.kill()
        if self.rect.x < 0 or self.rect.x > 1200:
            self.kill()

        self.rect.y += self.velocity.y
        offset = circlex - self.rect.x, circley - self.rect.y
        if p := self.mask.overlap(circle_mask, offset):
            v = pygame.Vector2(p)
            self.velocity.reflect_ip(v)


    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)


circle = pygame.Surface((400, 400))
pygame.draw.circle(circle, (255, 255, 255), (200, 200), 150)
circle_rect = circle.get_rect(topleft = (400, 100))
circle.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
circle_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(circle)

gun = pygame.Surface((100, 40))
gun_rect = gun.get_rect(topleft = (200, 750))
gun.fill("red")

bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()

while True:
    mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            b = Bullet(mx, 750)
            bullets.add(b)

    screen.fill((30, 30, 30))


    gun_rect.centerx = mx
    screen.blit(gun, gun_rect)
    screen.blit(circle, circle_rect)

    bullets.update(circle_rect.x, circle_rect.y, circle_mask)
    bullets.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(120)
```

the issue is the bullet is getting straight through the circle, if you could explain how vector works that would be great.
[image: vid]

Comment: look at the image from https://stackoverflow.com/q/76686989/9938317

Comment: hmm i'd have to learn those stuff its not simple ughh

Comment: any more info plz if u could give, concepts  etcs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the position by both components of the direction vector

```py
self.rect.center += self.velocity
```

Detect the collision of the circle with the bullet, not the other way around:

```py
offset = self.rect.x - circle_rect.x, self.rect.y - circle_rect.y
if p := circle_mask.overlap(self.mask, offset):
```

The reflection vector is the vector from the center of the circle the the hit position:

```py
v = pygame.Vector2(p) - (circle_rect.width/2, circle_rect.height/2)
```

Complete update method:

```py
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def update(self, circle_rect, circle_mask):
        if self.rect.y < 0 or self.rect.y > 800:
            self.kill()
        if self.rect.x < 0 or self.rect.x > 1200:
            self.kill()

        self.rect.center += self.velocity
        offset = self.rect.x - circle_rect.x, self.rect.y - circle_rect.y
        if p := circle_mask.overlap(self.mask, offset):
            v = pygame.Vector2(p) - (circle_rect.width/2, circle_rect.height/2)
            self.velocity.reflect_ip(v)
            
# [...]

while True:
    # [...]

    bullets.update(circle_rect, circle_mask)

    # [...]
```

[image]

Comment: ahh man i knew u'd come to save me, THanks alot i got the idea.

Comment: sir, i have a question, this does work with irregular shape eg heart for example, what would be the approach for that, i replaced it with a heart which gives some odd results
see here
https://i.imgur.com/CoRLdEv.gif

Comment: @Muhammadhuzaifa No, this doesn't work for irregular shapes because you need to calculate the normal vector for the point on the shape where the projectile hits the shape. For a circle, this is easy because the normal vector is always the vector from the center to the point of impact. For an irregular shape, however, there is no way to do this in general. You have to determine the outside of the shape and tessellate it into line segments. Finally, you can use the normal vector of the line.

Comment: hmm alright i got the idea, i'll learn more about it, thanks for helping